# How can I set all of the lines below each other

Tags: spacing

How can I set all of the lines below each other(in a subsection). 
[image: for example these tow sentences in the picture: Investigation in the Composite Production Process and Their Applications in Industry Companys Profit Maximization Using Nonlinear Programming and GAMS]

Comment: Are you looking for a simple `tabular` environment with `lp{}` alignment?  Welcome to the site.  Something like `\begin{tabular}{lp{4in}}
Aug. 2015 & \lipsum[1]\\
Jan. 2016 & \lipsum[2]\\
Aug. 2016 & \lipsum[3]
\end{tabular}` (using the `lipsum` package, for example).

Comment: As an alternative to `tabular`, the `itemize` environment could be employed, with custom labels.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tabularx` and its `X` column type.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
  Aug. 2015 & \bfseries Investigation in the Composite Production Process and
              Their Applications in Industry\\
  Jan. 2016 & Manufacturing Process 2\\
  Aug. 2016 & \bfseries Company Profit Maximization Using Nonlinear Programming
              and GAMS 
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

If you want the **outer spaces** being removed, you can use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX@{}}`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution with the `description` environment. It can break across pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text. 

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries, labelwidth=20mm, leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep]
  \item[Aug. 2015] \textbf{Investigation in the Composite Production Process and their Applications in Industry}
  \item[Jan. 2016] Manufacturing Process 2

  \item[Aug. 2016]\textbf{Company’s Profit Maximisation Using Nonlinear Programmation and GAMS}
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]